# Button particle effect Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I want to show the particle effect when I press the button as shown in the `gif` below.

[image]

https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids. That is the `Github` link for the android which I found.Is there any code examples for that effect in `iOS Swift`?

Comment: Check out CAEmitterLayer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caemitterlayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

agibson007 is correct. `CAEmitterLayer` is a way to go. You can start from here: http://prabhu.xyz/2017/05/08/particle-effects-in-swift-using-caemitterlayer.html

Quoted from that link:

> CAEmitterLayer is the api of choice to do particle effects in UIKit

Also, I've found this old library that still works, of course, written by Marin Todorov: https://github.com/icanzilb/UIEffectDesignerView